# regexp : check the string pattern

Tags: regex, sed, tcl

I want check the string pattern of these strings:

```
1) name.
2) name.{j}.
3) name.{j}.name.{i}.
4) name.{j}.name.{i}.param
```

how to check if the string 1 finish with only `"."` [pattern 1]

how to check if the string 2 finish with only `".{j}."` [pattern 2]

how to check if the string 3 contain `".{j}."` and finish with only  [pattern 3]`".{j}."`

how to check if the string 4 contain `".{j}."` and finish with only `".{j}.string"` [pattern 4]

here is the pattern of the proc which will be used

> ```
> proc check_patern {string} {
>
> /* if string match the pattern 1*/
> set res [check string $pattern1 $string]
> if {res ==1}
> puts "string match pattern 1"
>
> /* elseif string match the pattern 2*/
> set res [check string $pattern2 $string]
> if {res ==1}
> puts "string match pattern 2"
> /* elseif string match the pattern 3*/
> set res [check string $pattern3 $string]
> if {res ==1}
> puts "string match pattern 3"
>
> /* elseif string match the pattern 4*/
> set res [check string $pattern4 $string]
> if {res ==1}
> puts "string match pattern 4"
> }
> ```

Comment: first one: "[a-z]."; second one [a-z].{[a-z]}, etc.

Comment: Its not clear what you want as a result. Is it only one true for all rules or you want to check it separately

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The patterns can be condensed into a single regular expression:

```
set pattern {\w+\.(?:\{[ij]\}\.(?:\w+)?)?$}

# or, expanded with comments
set pattern {(?x)
    \w+\.               # a word followed by a dot
    (?:\{[ij]\}\.       # optionally followed by "{j}."
        (?:\w+)?        # which is optionally followed by a word
    )?                  #
    $                   # anchored at the end of the string
}

set lines {
    "0) do not match me"
    "1) name."
    "2) name.{j}."
    "3) name.{j}.name.{i}."
    "4) name.{j}.name.{i}.param"
    "5) name.{j}"
}

foreach line $lines {
    if {[regexp $pattern $line]} {puts $line}
}
```

lines 1-4 are output, not line 0 or 5